# Link AccessToken to a user in Loopback

Tags: access-token, strongloop, loopback

I wanted to add a custom attribute (`expireAt`) to the access token for it to be used by MongoDB to automatically remove the expired access token when expired.

Adding the custom attribute while creating the access token using `AccessToken` model is working well:

```
const ttl = 600;

const expireAt = new Date();
expireAt.setSeconds(expireAt.getSeconds() + ttl);

const token = await AccessToken.create({ ttl, expireAt });
```

However, when I want to create an access token for a user, I can't add the custom attribute `exprieAt` when creating the token, so I have create first, and then update it:

```
const ttl = 600;

const expireAt = new Date();
expireAt.setSeconds(expireAt.getSeconds() + ttl);

// Create the access token for the user
const token = await user.createAccessToken(options);
// Update token to set the custom date and time to expire
token.expireAt = expireAt;
token.save();

// Return the token together with the user data
return Object.assign({}, token.toJSON(), { user });
```

Is there a way I can create the token for a user with the custom attribute (either using instance method or model method is fine), without doing two steps - create and update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that `AccessToken` model has the relationship set up with the user via `userId` attribute (ref: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/master/common/models/access-token.json#L27).

```
{
  "name": "AccessToken",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string",
      "id": true
    },
    "ttl": {
      "type": "number",
      "ttl": true,
      "default": 1209600,
      "description": "time to live in seconds (2 weeks by default)"
    },
    "scopes": {
      "type": ["string"],
      "description": "Array of scopes granted to this access token."
    },
    "created": {
      "type": "Date",
      "defaultFn": "now"
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "user": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "User",
      "foreignKey": "userId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    }
  ]
}
```

To link the token to the user, we only need to pass in the value `userId`:

```
AccessToken.create({ ttl, expireAt, userId });
```